# Как правильно удалить созданный Диалог?

Tags: java, android

Создаю диалог со своей разметкой:

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.set_asp_dlg,null);

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.aAspect) + " " + l_asp.get(CurItem));

    adb.setView(layout);

    Button btDlgInpNameOk = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btDlgOk);
    Button btDlgInpNameCancel = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btDlgCancel);
    final Dialog dialog = adb.create();
    btDlgInpNameOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismissDialog(id);
        }
    });
    btDlgInpNameCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismissDialog(id);
        }
    });
    return dialog;
}
```

Вызываю Диалог:

```
showDialog(1);
```

При вызове диалога повторно, появляется этот же диалог, но в разметке должны быть изменения зависящие от переменной CurItem (название у tvTitle меняется).

Может я неправильно удаляю диалог? Как добиться чтобы диалог каждый раз создавался в зависимости от условий?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо удалять диалог, надо просто ловить/перегружать метод `onPrepareDialog()`

Дело в том, что `onCreateDialog()` вызывается при первом создании диалога и пока он не будет выгружен из памяти осью он не будет больше вызываться, чтобы изменить значения диалога перед показом, надо эти изменения делать в методе `onPrepareDialog()`

Метод правда устаревший, равно как и `onCreateDialog()` - теперь православным признается только `DialogFragment`

Comment: Спасибо! А можно поподробнее, как в моей ситуации это реализовать?

Comment: а в DialogFragment такой проблемы нет?

Comment: @kaaa - вы ничего не поняли, это не проблема, а фича - чувствуете разницу?